# Cbind invalid subscript type 'list' on data set

Tags: r, testing, dataframe

I'm trying to implement *Knn*, although when trying to set my train data, I get the error below:

> invalid subscript type 'list'

Here's my code:

```
rm(list=ls())
library(class)

library(ISLR)

train = subset(Weekly, Year >= 1990)
test = subset(Weekly, Year >= 2009)
Weekly.Lag1 = Weekly[,c("Lag1")]
Weekly.Lag2 = Weekly[,c("Lag2")]

train.X <- cbind(Weekly.Lag1,Weekly.Lag2)[train,]
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve it?

Comment: What is `train`?  A data frame?  If so it's a list, and lists cannot be used for subsetting rows.

Comment: @RichScriven It is reproducible, the dataset is in the `ISLR` package

Comment: @GregMiller, why are you using `[train,]` after the `cbind()`?

Comment: So, what part of "lists cannot be used for subsetting rows." don't you understand? And ... what does this actually mean: "trying to set my train data"?

Comment: @PauloMiraMor I meant for train to be a boolean vector, will come back after testing with the change..

Comment: Use str() to look at `train` and `cbind(Weekly.Lag1, Weekly.Lag2)`. How are we supposed to use a dataframe to subset a matrix? What is the intent here. Describe your goals in greater detail.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can understand. What is your expected output?  The way it now, `cbind` will just concatenate 2 columns selected from `Weekly`.

Comment: @42- apologies for not being more specific on the matter. After the previous comment mentioned train, I noticed it wasn't a boolean vector, but I should've been using a boolean vector. All is working now :-) I simply wanted to take all values from Weekly$Lag1 and Weekly$Lag2, and apply the train boolean vector for all values of TRUE

Comment: I've just changed it to (I apologize for the formatting):

        train = (Weekly$Year >= 1990 & Weekly$Year <= 2008)
        test = (Weekly$Year >= 2009 & Weekly$Year <= 2010)
        
        train.X <- cbind(Weekly$Lag1,Weekly$Lag2)[train,]

Comment: As suggestion, it is generally inadvisable to use packages (particularly unusual packages) in your question unless they are required for an answer.  If you were debugging something which used the `ISLR` package, that would be one thing, but many people will be unwilling to download a package just to get a sample data set.  There are a number of base `R` data sets you maybe able to use instead.  You can get a list using `library(help = "datasets")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rm(list=ls())
library(class)

library(ISLR)

train = which(Weekly$Year >= 1990) # you have to create vector not subset
test = which(Weekly$Year >= 2009) # you have to create vector not subset
Weekly.Lag1 = Weekly[,c("Lag1")]
Weekly.Lag2 = Weekly[,c("Lag2")]

train.X <- cbind(Weekly.Lag1,Weekly.Lag2)[train,]
```

Comment: I ended up doing it a different way, but producing the vector was indeed what fixed it. Thanks!